# Count, inner join

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions, inner-join

I have two tables:

`DRIVER(Driver_Id,First name,Last name,...);`

```
PARTICIPANT IN CAR ACCIDENT(Participant_Id,Driver_Id-foreign key,responsibility-yes or no,...).
```

Now, I need to find out which driver participated in accident where responsibility is 'YES', and how many times. I did this:

```
Select Driver_ID, COUNT (Participant.Driver_ID)as 'Number of accidents'
from Participant in car accident
where responsibility='YES'
group by Driver_ID
order by COUNT (Participant.Driver_ID) desc
```

But, I need to add drivers first and last name from the first table(using inner join, I suppose). I don't know how, because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you need to use an inner join. And because the first name and last name are now part of the SELECT, you also need to include those columns in the GROUP BY.

```
Select Driver_ID, First_name, Last_name COUNT (Participant.Driver_ID) as "Number of accidents"
from "Participant in car accident" join Driver on "Participant in car accident".Driver_ID = Driver.Driver_ID
where responsibility='YES'
group by Driver_ID, First_name, Last_name
order by COUNT (Participant.Driver_ID) desc
```

Is this homework?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine! And it's not homework, I am just trying to make my job easier by creating simple database, and I am a beginner in this field, so everyone can expect more stupid questions like this one :))

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline table:

```
SELECT d.driver_first_name,
       d.driver_last_name,
       r.incident_count
FROM  DRIVER d
INNER JOIN (SELECT driver_id, 
                   count(*) incident_count
            FROM PARTICIPANT_IN_CAR_ACCIDENT
            WHERE responsibility = 'YES'
            GROUP BY driver_id) r
    ON d.driver_id = r.driver_id
ORDER BY r.incident_count DESC
```

Should work.